# PyMySQL + WSGI / Flask nginx Internal Server Error

Tags: python, nginx, flask, pymysql

I have Flask Installed with PyMysql

When im running it in dev mode `python test.py` then everything is allright and in browser im able to see result of SQL Select under port 5000

When im running through Nginx `service test start` which is using WSGI then im getting Internal Server Error. I guess its not a port issue but rather user access issue? I have no idea why same file is running fine in DEV but not under WSGI. Or it could be that under nginx it cant identify localhost?

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import pymysql

db = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "123", "test1")

app = Flask(__name__)
#api = api(app)

@app.route('/')
def someName():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql = "SELECT name,password FROM Users"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    return results[0] + str(results[1])
#    return render_template('index.html', results=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
    app.debug = true
```

**nginx configuration**

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;

  # root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

   # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
   server_name mywebsite.com;

   location / { try_files $uri @rocket; }
      location @rocket {
      include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/rocket/myproject.sock;
   }

   location /images {
    alias /var/www/rocket/im;
    index index.html;
    }

   location /phpmyadmin {
      root /usr/share/;
      index index.php index.html index.htm;
      location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
         try_files $uri =404;
         root /usr/share/;
         fastcgi_pass unix:///run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_index index.php;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
      }
      location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
         root /usr/share/;
      }
   }
   location /phpMyAdmin {
      rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
   }
}
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from rocket import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
    app.debug = true
```

**app.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

logto = /var/www/rocket/%n.log
```

**error.log**
--- No python application found, check your startup logs for errors

Comment: You need to post your wsgi and nginx config to.

Comment: added all relevant stuff